# Stata merging changing my values?

Tags: merge, stata

I feel like I'm missing something really basic here...
I am trying to merge two datasets in Stata, FranceSQ.dta and FranceHQ.dta. They both have a variable that I created named "uid" that uniquely identifies the observations.

```
use FranceSQ, clear
merge 1:1 uid using FranceHQ, gen(_merge) keep(match)
```

Now what's confusing me is that it tells me that uid doesn't uniquely identify my observations. What I realized it happening is that when I open FranceSQ, everything is normal, and when I look at my uid variable, I have the following values...

```
25010201
25010202
25010203
...
```

But then once I try to run the merge, it changes all of my values, so that I see...

```
2.50101e+10
2.50101e+10
2.50101e+10
...
```

Any help would be very appreciated...I'm sure there's a simple answer but it's eluding me at the moment.

*** *EDIT* *****
So Nick's advice helped, thanks! This is what I was doing that went wrong, so I wonder if someone could point out why it didn't work.

1) I created the uid variable in each dataset by concatenating two numeric variables, which cast the uid variable as a string.
2) I ran destring on the whole dataset (because there were a lot of incorrectly cast variables), which turned uid into a double.
3) Then I recast uid as a string. It was with this that I was unable to do the initial merge. I noticed that the value it was changing all of my observations to was the last value in the dataset.
4) Just because I was tweaking around, I recast the uid variable as double, and was getting the same results.

Now I finally got it to work by just starting over and not recasting the uid variable as a string in the first place, but I'm still at a loss as to why my previous efforts did not work, or how the merge command actually decided to change my values.

Comment: Best not to use the word "recast" in this context as there is a `recast` command. I think you are alluding to a `tostring` operation in the middle, which probably should have included a `format()` option specifying a numeric format that would retain all the digits.

Comment: It would be best if you posted your code, otherwise we can only vaguely guess what was it that you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely, this is a problem with precision. Long integers need to be held in `long` or `double` data types. You might need to `recast` one identifier before the `merge`.

You should check by looking at the results of `describe` whether `uid` has the same data type in both datasets.

Answer (score 2):

1. To check whether your variable really identifies observations, type `isid uid`. Stata would complain if `uid` is not a unique identifier when performing `merge`, anyway, but that's a useful check on its own. If `uid` passes the check in both files, it should still do so in the merged file; it must be failing in at least one of the source files in order to fail in the merged file.
2. On top of Nick Cox' answer concerning [data types](http://stata.com/help.cgi?data%20types), the issue may simply be formatting. Type `describe uid` to find out what the current format is, and may be `format uid %12.0f` to get rid of the scientific notation.
3. I think Stata promotes variables to the more accurate format when it needs to, say when you `replace` an integer-valued variable with non-integer values; same thing should happen with `merge` when you have say `byte` values in one data set, and you merge in `float` values on the same variable from the other data set.
4. Missing values in `uid` may be the reason Stata does not believe this variable works well. Check for these, too, before and after `merge` (see `help data types` that I references above concerning the valid ranges for each type).